# Laravel token generation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to create an user token in laravel with passport, and when I try to call the service it gives me the data of the token and not the token.

Using the passport in the model of the user :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

And controller for the login like

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public $successStatus = 200;

    public function login()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

The response of the service is:

```json
{
    "success": {
        "token": {
            "name": "MyApp",
            "abilities": [
                "*"
            ],
            "tokenable_id": 1,
            "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-29T22:52:58.000000Z",
            "created_at": "2022-03-29T22:52:58.000000Z",
            "id": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to get a response like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`'use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens'`

Instead of

`'use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens'`